# Amadeus Service 'No fare for booking code ' error in Fare_Informativebestpricing

Tags: amadeus

I am working on to call the Amadeus Service and get the response for flight search and then book.

Amadeus service method  _InformativeBestPricingWithoutPNR is giving following error 
1) 'NO VALID FARE/RULE COMBINATIONS FOR PRICING' 
2) 'NO FARE FOR BOOKING CODE-TRY OTHER PRICING OPTIONS'
3) 'No INTERLINE AGREEMENT - PRICE SEPARATELY'

Just to know that i am calling Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoard and then select one flight and call the Fare_InformativeBestpricingWithoutPNR , some of the flight is giving proper response in Fare_InformativeBestpricing but some of the are giving error, 
Please help, i have read all the document provide by Amadeus extranet site and related document , there are no any solution provide for specific error.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already read it, I'd definitely suggest you log in to [webservices.amadeus.com](https://webservices.amadeus.com/) and take a look at the [Amadeus WBS Implementation Guide - Internet Booking Engine with Master Pricer](https://webservices.amadeus.com/extranet/kdbViewDocument.do?externalId=ncewbspdt7_3177&docStatus=Published&mpId=se__581_1__5_functional&serviceVersionId=4507).

Typically these errors occur because only a subset of the journey returned by Travel Board is being sent to Informative Bestpricing, and this subset is not valid for pricing on its own.

A typical case when this can occur is if you price each leg individually but the Fare Basis used may only apply for a round trip.

Could you please provide more information on the call you are making to `Fare_InformativeBestpricingWithoutPNR`?

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are combining two different airlines that do not have interline agreements. So in this case you will have to price them separately. For example if you are flying american airlines for the outbound flight, then you cannot fly air france in the inbound flight and price them in one transaction. in this case, assuming American and Air France do not have interline agreements, you have to price them separately.